# Google Sheet run Macro write Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet filled in via Google Forms. Once a new row is added, I need to run a script to see if the field in 'column G' is NOT empty. Then script should then create a comment tagging a particular email address. I tried to create a macro but don't understand how to do it and can't write code! Help!

I "recorded a macro" but clearly didn't do it right.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up an onFormSubmit trigger with trigger handler named onMyFormSubmit.  Column G is question six.

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  if(!e.values[6]) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(gobj.globals.emailpriv,"Column 7",`Column 7 is null at row ${e.range.rowStart} sheet ${e.range.getSheet().getName()}`);
  }
}
```

- [onFormSubmit(e) Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)